I lost the keys for a gate's lock. Where can I find a replacement cylinder or how can I get new keys?
I lost the keys for a gate's lock and I need to find a replacement cylinder or a way to craft new keys.
The cylinder has a peculiar shape. I couldn't find any brand on the gate or lock. I did find a similar lock online with the name "PREFER 6610", but the whole lock piece doesn't seem compatible with mine.
I'm attaching a bunch of pictures: the lock still installed in the gate, the opened up lock and some pictures of the cylinder.






Taking the cylinder to a local locksmith should work.

Who's the maker of the cylinder?

This is one of those times where "take it to a pro" is the cheapest and easiest answer, short of changing the lock to a chain and padlock.

Finding something that will fit that with knowing the model of gate exactly might be really really hard.    Finding it not knowing that info maybe close to impossible.    The fact is a locksmith can probably make you a key or/and help you replace the lockset.

Exactly this. Many years ago I lost the keys for my garage door (which certainly based on the photos was visually similar). I stripped out the barrel as OP has done, took it to a local locksmith. He asked me to come back in an hour, by which time he had hand-crafted a new key and machined a couple of duplicates.

A locksmith can also usually re-key the lock, and provide you with new (different) keys, if you're worried about the old keys being found and used maliciously.

Are you in Italy by chance? This lock looks very similar in principle to a garage door lock of the same brand (Prefer) I had while living there: the cylinder drives two plates that move a pair of rods, one at the top and one at the bottom – except that the garage door had a wider body and the cylinder allowed the key to be inserted from either side. I see the Prefer 6610 is also being sold in France.
In my case, I found a replacement garage door lock at the local hardware store – OBI, Brico IO, Granbrico and the like. At least one of them might also have a matching lock for your gate. You’ll most likely replace not only the cylinder but then entire lock assembly – the piece you removed from the gate and took apart. What you want to look out for:

drive for two rods with the same distance between the two rods (in locked/unlocked state, respectively)
cylinder that fits through the faceplate of your lock
compatible mount points
compatible external dimensions


Looks like some variation of "Euro Cylinder" to me.
Not that that helps much, as those come in various sizes, and your one is a slightly different shape so you would probably need to compare directly with the replacement.

The Euro Cylinder is shown here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zylinderset.jpg Note that is quite different from the cylinder in OP’s lock, both in terms of how the cylinder drives the lock mechanism and the way the cylinder is attached to the lock.
